# Why "npm run <command>" does not work anywhere?

Tags: node.js, npm

`npm run` doesn't work on any project. Because of this, I can not install packages where there is a post-installed script for example

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'test'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.13.4
3 info using node@v13.5.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'pretest', 'test', 'posttest' ]
5 info lifecycle myapp@0.0.0~pretest: myapp@0.0.0
6 info lifecycle myapp@0.0.0~test: myapp@0.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle myapp@0.0.0~test: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle myapp@0.0.0~test: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\Vombat\Desktop\Learn\express_template_app\myapp\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\Vombat\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Vombat\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Vombat\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle myapp@0.0.0~test: CWD: C:\Users\Vombat\Desktop\Learn\express_template_app\myapp
10 silly lifecycle myapp@0.0.0~test: Args: [ '-c', 'node -v' ]
11 info lifecycle myapp@0.0.0~test: Failed to exec test script
12 silly lifecycle myapp@0.0.0~test: Returned: code: -4058  signal: null
13 info lifecycle myapp@0.0.0~test: Failed to exec test script
14 verbose stack Error: myapp@0.0.0 test: `node -v`
14 verbose stack spawn = ENOENT
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:267:19)
14 verbose stack     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
14 verbose stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
15 verbose pkgid myapp@0.0.0
16 verbose cwd C:\Users\Vombat\Desktop\Learn\express_template_app\myapp
17 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18362
18 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "test"
19 verbose node v13.5.0
20 verbose npm  v6.13.4
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error syscall spawn =
23 error file =
24 error path =
25 error errno -4058
26 error myapp@0.0.0 test: `node -v`
26 error spawn = ENOENT
27 error Failed at the myapp@0.0.0 test script.
27 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
28 verbose exit [ -4058, true ]
```

I updated the node to the latest version, I tried `npm cache clear --force` and `npm cache verify`, didnt help.
OS Windows 10.
node version `13.5.0`, npm version `6.13.4`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the `NODE_PATH` environment variable set correctly.
The path must match your nodeJS directory + `\node_modules`

[image]

Comment: I create system variable `NODE_PATH` with value `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules`, didn`t help

Comment: Make sure you restart the computer for the variable to work.

Comment: Then you have to provide more information on the error.